# how to free memory in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I'm writing a C program but i'm getting some memory errors so i decided to make a small  program to see when and how to deallocate memory.

My example :

```
int main() {
    char *a=malloc(5);
    a="mama";
    char *b=malloc(strlen(a));
    printf("%s\n",a);
    strcpy(b,a);
    free(a);
    printf("%s\n",b);
    return 0;
```

}

here i'm getting an error :

> *** Error in `./a': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400757 ***

but when i change just one line :

```
int main() {
    char *a=malloc(5);
    strcpy(a,"mama");
    char *b=malloc(strlen(a));
    printf("%s\n",a);
    strcpy(b,a);
    free(a);
    printf("%s\n",b);
    return 0;
```

}

My second  program is working well, so why i'm getting this error in the first?
i hope that you can explain me why.

In My Real program I'm doing like that :

```
    char * getDate(){

    char *date=malloc(5);
    //some instructions here
    return date;
}


int main() {
    char *a=malloc(5);//im sure that a will not exceed 5 bytes
    a=getDate();
    return 0;
}
```

It's just a small example , and i don't know where to free memory .so how and where i can free memory , have I to free date or the char pointer?

**Edited second Time:**

```
void getDate(char *a){
        //some instructions here
    strcpy(a,"haha");

}
int main() {
        char *a=malloc(5);
            getDate(a);
            int i= strlen(a);
            printf("%s and the size is :%d\n",a,i);
            free(a);
            return 0;
 }
```

what are  the rules i have to follow to avoid memory errors.

many thanks.

Comment: `char *a=malloc(5)` - don't use magic numbers.

Comment: You aren't allocating enough memory for `b`.  Remember, `strlen` doesn't count the terminating null byte, so you need to add one to it when allocating `b`..

Comment: [sigh] leak in the first two lines:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the line:

```
char *a=malloc(5);
```

You assign `a` with the address of a dynamically allocated memory block, but then in the line:

```
a="mama";
```

You *reassign* it with the address of the literal string constant `"mama"`. Discarding the pointer to the dynamically allocated block so that when you call

```
free(a);
```

`a` is no longer a valid heap memory block, and cannot be deallocated.

Strings (and arrays in general) in C are not data first-class types and cannot be assigned.  You should replace:

```
a="mama";
```

with

```
strcpy( a, "mama" ) ;
```

The assignment sets the pointer value - it *does not* copy `"mama"` to the memory points to by `a`.  The `strcpy()` call on teh other hand copies the string to the dynamic memory block *referenced* by `a`.

In your second code fragment, you are "leaking" the memory allocated in `main()` since you have reassigned `a` without freeing the original block.  Although in your example you have not free'd `a`, it remains freeable, because the allocation in `GetDate()` is dynamic. As a coding style, dynamically allocating memory in a function and returning its pointer is a bad idea since it makes it the responsibility of the caller to know that the memory was dynamically allocated and must be free'd, and  it invites memory leaks.

Comment: thanks for the response, thank you, but what do you think when using a method to reteurn a char pointer , is it the same thing? and where i have to free the memory in the main method or in the method called ,see the last pgm.

Comment: @jeanjack :  I have added a note on that, but in the second you do not even call free(), so you are not comparing like-for-like.  The error message clearly indicates that it is the call to free() that fails at runtime.  Nonetheless, in the second `a` remains freeable because it is assigned a dynamically allocated block.  Note also that the runtime is not required to issue an error when free() fails - that is implementation dependent.

Comment: thank you , a clear answer , i have edited my second pgm , ithink it is a good way to free memory.